# What are the metadata objects that does not require the run test classes in Production

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, metadata, production

I'm trying to find the list of all the metadatas objects that we can deploy to production without having to trigger the run of all test classes

For example I know that we can deploy ListViews, Reports, profiles... without running the test classes

Is there an exhaustive list?

Comment: There is an exhaustive blacklist and it's very short. Any change containing Apex code requires tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on version of Metadata API. [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_running_tests.htm) is a list of all metadata, that causes test execution before 34.0.

> If the deployment includes components for the following metadata
>   types, all local tests are run.
>
> - ApexClass
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage
> - ApexTrigger
> - ArticleType
> - BaseSharingRule
> - CriteriaBasedSharingRule
> - CustomDataType
> - CustomField
> - CustomObject
> - DataCategoryGroup
> - Flow
> - InstalledPackage
> - NamedFilter
> - OwnerSharingRule
> - PermissionSet
> - Profile
> - Queue
> - RecordType
> - RemoteSiteSetting
> - Role
> - SharingReason
> - Territory
> - Validation Rules
> - Workflow

If Metadata API is version 34.0 and higher, only deployment of Apex class or Apex trigger causes deployment test execution.

> When deploying to production, all tests, except those that originate
>   from managed packages, are executed if your deployment package
>   contains Apex classes or triggers. If your package doesn’t contain
>   Apex components, no tests are run by default.